# How do I solve the puzzle with ten symbols each with six boxes?

Tags: fez

It's a purple room off of the giant throne room in the sky warp zone with a platform that has six purple crates and a pillar with two columns of five box symbols.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15):

That room is showing unfolded cubes (called nets) in 2 dimensions. There are 11 different ways to unfold a cube and only 10 shown on the pillar.

Here are the 11 cube nets:
[image]

Lay the blocks out in the missing 11th way.

Answer (score 6):

See image below:

> Use the six cubes to make a Z-block:
>
>  [image: unfolding a cube]

This last setup is the last/11th (unpictured) way to unfold a cube.

Comment: Could you put that in an spoiler block (`>!`) that way we have a clue-only option still.

Comment: At this point, spoiling an answer five years old is helping nothing at all.  Just leave it alone.

Comment: @Frank Agree mostly, but some of us actually do play games on a [five-year lag](https://www.xkcd.com/606/).

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt I know; I'm one of them.  But it doesn't change the fact that we're here to *answer questions*.  If you don't want to be spoiled, don't read the question and accompanying answers.  You have to sort of expect to be spoiled if you're reading questions about a specific game.  As we don't dance around that fact, I have rolled back the spoiler protection.